# Python Class elements as Function parameters

Tags: python

```
class params:
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
  d = 4
```

I know it is not possible to pass all four elements of the class to a function, which takes a total of four parameters by just doing

> function(class)

Is this the only way

> function(a,b,c,d)

or is there an other solution?

Comment: Is there a reason to have the values in a class? If they were in a dictionary, you could call `function(**param_dict)`, which seems like what you want.

Comment: that exactly what i wanted, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class params:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4

    def __call__(self):
        r = dict()
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not attr.startswith('_'):
                r[attr] = getattr(self, attr)
        return r

p = params()
function(**p())
```

However, this is quite hacky and probably not very maintainable: if for some reason the function call for `function` changes, you need to modify the class also.

(Perhaps using a `tuple()` instead of `dict()` for `r` might be a bit more flexible, but still not a solution I would highly recommend...)

Answer (score 1):

I think 4 arguments is acceptable. But if you do want, define a function such as `func(a, *args, **kargs)` is a choice. Any of the three parameters is optional. I do think there is no need to create such a class to do something that Python has already done, and do much better. For more about function arguments, check [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).